# How do you prove that a symmetric matrix is always diagonalizable even though there are eigenvalues whose multiplicity $k\ge2$?

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, diagonalization

I want to make sure that the symmetric matrix is always diagonalizable. So I'm studying proof 2 [here](http://maecourses.ucsd.edu/~mdeolive/mae280a/lecture11.pdf). But I cannot understand why the following formula holds.
$$0=v^*(A-\lambda_iI)^2v=v^*(A-\lambda_iI)(A-\lambda_iI)\ne0$$
Where is $v$ in the second equation? Is there any other easy-to-understand proof of the diagonalization of the symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the second equation should end with v.  Then, for $M=A-\lambda I$, which is symmetric,
$$\vec{0} = M^2v,\text{ so }\\0=v^*MMv = v^*M^*Mv = (Mv)^*(Mv) = |Mv|^2 \neq 0 $$

Another explanation is here:

http://www.quandt.com/papers/basicmatrixtheorems.pdf

Comment: It seems that this reasoning proves only that there are no generalized eigenvalues of order 2. With slight modification it can be generalized onto the case of arbitrary even orders. But what about odd ones?

Comment: @user355705 I think the proof method in the attachment is general to both odd and even numbers. Because it have proved that there is no generalized eigenvector with k = 2 for eigenvalues whose multiplicity is greater than 2.

Comment: @metamath You are right. Indeed an eigenvector with a higher rank necessary possess an associated generalized eigenvector of order 2. Sorry for the wrong remark. But actually it is not necessary to introduce the concept of generalized eigenvectors for the proof of the claim (see below).

Answer (score 3):

The $v$ has disappeared in a typo, and that line should've been
$$
v^*(A-\lambda_iI)(A-\lambda_iI)v = \|(A-\lambda_iI)v\|^2
$$
The right-hand side is gotten precisely because $A$ is symmetric.

We see this is gives a contradiction because we assumed that $v$ was a generalized eigenvector of order $2$, and thus the right-hand side is non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

The following proof does not require introduction of generalized eigenvectors and demonstrates that all eigenvectors of a normal matrix have order (rank) 1.

Assume that $n\times n$ normal matrix $A$ has an eigenvector $v$ of order (rank) $m>1$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$.

In terms of the matrix
$$
M=A-\lambda I
$$
this means 
$$
M^m\nu=0; \forall \{k: 1\le k<m\}: M^k\nu\ne0.
$$

Define
$$
l=\left\lceil\frac{m}{2}\right\rceil.\tag{1}
$$
Observe that for odd $m$:
$$
M^{2l}\nu=M^{m+1}\nu=MM^m\nu=0.
$$
The same equality $M^{2l}\nu=0$ is valid for even $m$, so that one can write irrespective of parity:
$$
0=\nu^*M^{2l}\nu=\nu^*M^{l}M^l\nu=\|M^l\nu\|^2\ne0,\tag{2}
$$
obtaining a contradiction. In (2) we used the facts that an integer power of a normal matrix is normal and that $l$ defined in (1) is strictly less than $m$ for $m>1$.