# Does an n by n Hermitian matrix always has n independent eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am learning the MIT ocw 18.06 Linear Algebra, and I have learnt:
an arbitrary $n×n$ matrix *A* with *n* independent eigenvectors can be written as
$A=SΛS^{-1}$, and then for the Hermitian matrices, because the eigenvectors can be chosen orthonormal, it can be written as $A=QΛQ^H$ further.

I wonder does every $n×n$ Hermitian matrix has *n* independent eigenvectors and why?
Thank you!

P.S. 
[MIT 18.06 Linear Algebra Lecture 25: Symmetric Matrices and Positive Definiteness.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umt6BB1nJ4w&list=PLE7DDD91010BC51F8&index=26)
You may wish to start from 4:20. From the course, I think the spectral theorem comes from diagonalizable matrix, it's just a special case, it's just the case eigenvectors are orthonormal. The eigenvectors of Hermitian matrices can be chosen orthnormal, but is every Hermitian matrix diagonalizable? If it is, why?

Comment: You mean independent eigenvectors, not independent eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I have edited it.

Comment: It's on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for the link, I had read the page though, and there wasn't an answer to my question.

Comment: Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627715/how-do-you-prove-that-a-symmetric-matrix-is-always-diagonalizable-even-though-th/2627861#2627861) for a simple proof.

Comment: @user355705 It's short and sweet. And I think that question is equally valid for Hermitian matrices, right?

Comment: In fact it is valid even for general normal matrices, as an integer power of a normal matrix is also normal. However the proof presumes knowledge about the rank of eigenvector and its connection with [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a theorem with a name: it is called the Spectral Theorem for Hermitian (or self-adjoint) matrices. As pointed out by Jose' Carlos Santos, it is a special case of the Spectral Theorem for normal matrices, which is just a little bit harder to prove.

Actually we can prove the spectral theorem for Hermitian matrices right here in a few lines.

We are going to have to think about linear operators rather than matrices.  If $T$ is a linear operator on a finite dimensional complex inner product space $V$, its adjoint $T^*$ is  another linear operator determined by $\langle T v, w\rangle = \langle v, T^* w \rangle$ for all $v, w \in V$. (Note this is a basis-free description.)  $T$ is called Hermitian or self-adjoint if $T = T^*$.

Let $B$ be an $n$-by-$n$ complex matrix and $B^*$ the conjugate transpose matrix.  Let $T_B$ and $T_{B^*}$ be the corresponding linear operators.  Then $(T_B)^* = T_{B^*}$, so a a matrix is Hermitian if and only if the corresponding linear operator is Hermitian.

Let $A$ be a Hermitian linear operator on  a complex inner product space $V$ of dimension $n$.  We need to consider $A$--invariant subspaces of $V$, that is linear subspaces $W$ such that $A W \subseteq W$.  We should think about such a subspace as on an equal footing as our original space $V$.  In particular, any such subspace is itself an inner product space, $A_{|W} : W \to W$ is a linear operator on $W$, and  $A_{|W}$ is also Hermitian.
If $\dim W \ge 1$,  $A_{|W}$ has an least one eigenvector $w \in W$ -- because any linear operator at all acting on a (non-zero) finite dimensional complex vector space has at least one eigenvector.

The basic phenomenon is this:    Let $W$ be any invariant subspace for $A$.    Then $W^\perp$ is also invariant under $A$. The reason is that if $w \in W$ and $x \in W^\perp$, then 
$$
\langle w, A x\rangle = \langle A^* w , x \rangle = \langle A w, x \rangle = 0,
$$
because $Aw \in W$ and $x \in W^\perp$.  Thus $A x \in W^\perp$.

Write $V  = V_1$. 
Take one eigenvector $v_1$ for $A$ in $V_1$.  Then $\mathbb C v_1$ is $A$--invariant.   Hence $V_2 = (\mathbb C v_1)^\perp$ is also $A$ invariant. Now just apply the same argument to $V_2$:  the restriction of $A$ to $V_2$ has an eigenvector $v_2$ and the perpendicular complement $V_3$  to $\mathbb C v_2$  in $V_2$ is $A$--invariant.   Continuing in this way, one gets a sequence of mutually orthogonal eigenvectors and a decreasing sequence of invariant subpsaces, $V =  V_1 \supset V_2 \supset V_3 \dots$ such that $V_k$ has dimension $n - k + 1$.  The process will only stop when we get to $V_n$ which has dimension 1.

Comment: You really hit the nail on the head as I'm afraid my question is too unusual to be understand. May I repeat you answer in my imprecise words?

Comment: Regard *A* as an operator on *V*, its invariant subspaces contains at least one eigenvector, their orthogonal complement are invariant subspaces too because A is a Hermitian matrix, we start from $\mathbb C^n$, every time we take a eigenvector from the space, it on a line which is a invariant subspace, and the space left which like a plane perpendicular to the line is also a invariant subspace, and we can take n times (i.e. *n* orthogonal/independent eigenvectors). Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: I still have some trouble with this, what if I take an eigenvector from the last space? As we know "Let $W$ be any invariant subspace for $A$. Then $W^⊥$ is also invariant under $A$", I take the eigenvector out, then there will be only zero vector left, and I think it really orthogonal to that eigenvector we take, is zero vector an invariant subspace? It may be, but "invariant space has at least one eigenvector" would be false. This "Let $W$ be any invariant subspace for $A$. Then $W^⊥$ is also invariant under $A$" makes me confused.

Comment: When you have reached $V_n$, you already have your collection of $n$ mutually orthogonal eigenvectors.  You can't go further and you don't need to go further.  I corrected the answer at one point to say that a linear operator on a *non-zero* finite dimensional complex vector space has an eigenvector.

Comment: As an exercise, try writing up the proof using mathematical induction.

Comment: It's important in the second paragraph that "acting on" means "mapping it into itself".

Comment: Thanks a lot, to be honest, with the lessons I've learnt, I really tried hard to understand this answer, but it's really beneficial. There is still some questions.

Comment: ①Does $⟨w,Ax⟩=⟨A^∗w,x⟩$ always work for any matrix? I think so, but I am not able to prove. ②Actually, every time we take an eigenvector out, but is there any possibility that some of them are the same? Because "any linear operator at all acting on a (non-zero) finite dimensional complex vector space has at least one eigenvector." tells us there will be at least one eigenvector in *A*, but don't tell us what it is, is it always in $V_k$? Why?

Comment: @lan Thanks for your kind reminder. I found this fact on the page https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_03.pdf. If *A* mapping *W* into itself, does it mean there's at least one eigenvector of *A* belonging to the *W*?

Comment: I'm going to sign off after this comment, because I have to do other things. How did you make those little circled numbers?    The answer to (1) is yes.  The answer to (2) is:  you consider $A_|W$, the restriction of $A$ to $W$ as an operator in its own right, and apply the theorem about the existence of eigenvectors to this operator; this shows there is an eigenvector in $W$.

Comment: That should have been $A_{| W}$, $A$ restricted to $W$.

Comment: Could you please give me some key words for further reading if there is not enough time to answer this question. Thank you so much. :) I think $A_{|W}$ and $A$ are the same thing, the only difference between them is that $A_{|W}$ indicates this thing having at least one eigenvector, $A_{|V1}$ indicates one eigenvector, $A_{|V2}$ indicates one eigenvector, but why should these ones be different?

Comment: Or why should these ones be in $V_1$ and $V_2$ separately?

Comment: Work out the example $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 &1\\0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $V_1=\mathbb C^3$ . Certainly $A$  is a linear operator on $\mathbb C^3$, $A_{|V1}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ will have at least one eigenvector. Since $V_1$ is whole $\mathbb C^3$, that one must be in $V_1$, maybe we could choose $v_1=(1, 0, 0)$.

Comment: Then we should choose $V_2$ as the plane in $\mathbb C^3$ perpendicular to the line through $(1, 0, 0)$, it's an $A$-invariant subspace, so  $A_{|V2}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ will have at least one eigenvector. But I don't understand why this one will actually be located in the plane and then naturally be independent of the first one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't distinguish carefully enough between matrices and linear operators.  Read my edited answer.  Think only in terms of linear operators. In the example, let $A$ be the linear operator whose matrix on $\mathbb C^3$ with respect to the standard basis is $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 &1\\0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: We insist now that $A$ is a linear operator.  If $W$ is some 2 dimensional invariant subspace, Then $A_{|W}$ is a linear operator from $W$ to $W$. Its matrix with respect to any chosen basis of $W$ is a 2 by 2 matrix.

Comment: Thank you for additional information, I find the word eigenvalue is also a concept for operators now. According to my understanding, what you mean is that "the perpendicular complement $V_3$  to $\mathbb C v_2$  in $V_2$ is $A_{|V2}$--invariant", and the eigenvectors of $A_{|V1}$, $A_{|V2}$, $A_{|V3}$ ... $A_{|Vn}$ are eigenvectors of $A$ too. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: This answer helps me a lot. Thank you fredgoodman!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has. That is due to the spectral theorem: every normal $n\times n$ matrix is diagonalizable. And Hermitian matrices are normal.

Comment: From my understanding, the factorization $A=QΛQ^H$ (i.e., the spectral theorem) is the special form of $A=SΛS^{-1}$ when *A* is a Hermitian matrix, and $A=SΛS^{-1}$ exists under the situation that there is a full set of independent eigenvectors. I wonder, if it is, why a Hermitian matrix is always diagonalizable?

Comment: @Thomas Because the spectral theorem says so.

Comment: From the course (I add the link into the question now), I think the spectral theorem comes from diagonalizable matrix, it's just a special case, it's just the case eigenvectors are orthonormal. The eigenvectors of Hermitian matrices can be chosen orthnormal, but is every Hermitian matrix diagonalizable? If it is, why?

Comment: @Thomas Every Heritian matrix is normal and every normal matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: I had not learnt the concept of normal matrix from the course. I search for it now, and I realize that all matrices can be written as $A=QTQ^H$ with triangular *T*, so $A^HA=AA^H$ would be $T^HT=TT^H$, for a 2 by 2 matrix, it's easy to prove the upper right corner entry of such *T* is 0, extend it to size *n*, and we prove that *T* is diagonal. Is that a right poof? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: It looks fine to me.